# Hazard-ratio of marginal effects?

Tags: survival, econometrics, probit, hazard, marginal-effect

I am doing a study on manipulated hospital discharges using a similar methodology as [this paper](https://pubs.aeaweb.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1257/aer.20170092). In short, we observe that patients are more likely to be discharged directly after a higher tariff rate has been reached, leading to distribution of discharges such as this:

[image]

1. I estimate the following probit model:  [image]

Where time is the duration of the treatment and the dummies are at the t=0 where the tariff changes and at t=-1, directly before the tariff changes.

2. Next I calculate the probability of a discharge at t=0 and at t=-1 and calculate the **hazard-ratio** by dividing those two. This would indicate the speed at which the probability of discharge changes between those two times.

Instead of the steps in 2., the referees of my paper would rather see average marginal effects at t=0 and t=-1.

**Question: If I calculate average marginal effects, can I still calculate their ratios and call that a hazard-ratio? I assume not. But how can I indicate the rate of change between the two times?**

Comment: Amazing paper by Eliason - glad to learn of it.  What exactly is the referee wanting you to marginalize (uncondition on)?  Why?  If you uncondition on an important variable the results are typically very hard to interpret and becoming secretly dependent on a hidden variable.  And how does the Eliason model differ from a Markov transition model?  Would it have been simpler to use a logistic model for transition (to discharge) probabilities?

Comment: @FrankHarrell: I do something similar to Table 4. in Eliason. I compare different subgroups to test whether certain patient characteristics affect the extent of discharge manipulation. The referee says that hazard-ratio is economically difficult to interpret and instead I should add interaction-terms to my probit model and calculate marginal effects for those. But the "rate of change" effect so nicely captured by Eliason is lost. Or is it not?

Comment: I would love to see you open that discussion on datamethods.org where a number of health services researchers may respond (and so will I).  datamethods is intended for discussions between subject matter researchers and quantitative methodologists (biostatisticians, epidemiologists, health services researchers, clinical trialists, informaticians).

Comment: @FrankHarrell: For example, when testing whether women are more likely to be manipulated I would run :  ```glm(close ~ time + time^2 + t_at + t_b4 + t_at*female + t_b4*female , family = binomial(link = "probit"), 
    data = mydata)```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will!